# Qlik Sense mashup RequireJS adding js files gives error 'not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, qliksense

So i never used requireJS before, but because Qlik Sense is using it for its mashups i had to try it one way or another.

I just made a simple bootstrap mashup, added the highcharts library and bought a bootstrap admin theme (name = Naut) on a theme website.

I moved everything i could use from the bought theme to the simple bootstrap mashup (css, html, js) and then i tried to modify the `require.config`

this is how my `require.config` file is looking at the moment.

Keep in mind that jQuery is default inside of the requireJS file (i think the developers of Qlik Sense have made it that way by default).

```
    var config = {
        host: window.location.hostname,
        prefix: "/",
        port: window.location.port,
        isSecure: window.location.protocol === "https:"
    };

    require.config( {
        baseUrl: ( config.isSecure ? "https://" : "http://" ) + config.host + (config.port ? ":" + config.port: "") + config.prefix + "resources",
        paths: {
            bootstrap: "/extensions/fitcloud/js/vendor/bootstrap.min",
            bootstrapSwitch: "/extensions/fitcloud/js/vendor/bootstrap-switch.min",
            highcharts: "/extensions/fitcloud/js/vendor/highcharts",
            senseutils: "/extensions/fitcloud/js/vendor/senseUtils",
            treefy: "/extensions/fitcloud/js/vendor/bootstrap-treefy.min",
            mainsc: "/extensions/fitcloud/js/main",
            vendor: "/extensions/fitcloud/scripts/vendor",
            plugins: "/extensions/fitcloud/scripts/plugins",
            main: "/extensions/fitcloud/scripts/main"
        },
        shim: {
            bootstrap : {
                deps : ['jquery']
            },
            bootstrapSwitch : {
                deps : ['jquery']
            },
            highcharts : {
                deps : ['jquery'],
                exports: 'Highcharts'
            },
            treefy : {
                deps : ['jquery']
            },
            mainsc : {
                deps : ['treefy']
            },
            senseutils : {
                deps : ['bootstrap']
            },
            vendor : {
                deps : ['jquery']
            },
            plugins : {
                deps : ['vendor']
            },
            main : {
                deps : ['plugins']
            }
        }
    } );

    require( ["js/qlik"], function ( qlik ) { qlik.setOnError( function ( error ) { alert( error.message ); } );
        require(["jquery", "bootstrap", "bootstrapSwitch", "highcharts", "senseutils", "treefy", "mainsc", "vendor", "plugins", "main"], function (jq, bs, bss, hs, su, tf, ms, ve, pl, ma) {

var app = qlik.openApp('test.qvf', config);


// All the rest of my javascript code goes in here

});
```

The js files `vendor, plugins & main` are the javascript files from the theme i bought. When i put them into the `require.config` and `require` i start getting errors `TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function` & `TypeError: $(...).bootstrapSwitch is not a function` and my app is broken, no charts are loaded and bootstrapSwitch buttons are not working eather. If i remove them, everthing is working fine except i don't have the interactivity the theme is having ( closing sidebar, bouncing menu, ... ).

Am i doing anything wrong, or could it be that some function names are used in multiple libraries?

Answer (score 2):

Your start of the extension should look like this (properties, qlik, jquery, always needed the js dependencies after that are optional but you will probably need

```
define(["./properties", "qlik","jquery","highcharts", "bootstrapSwitch"], 
    function(Props, qlik,$,highcharts,boostrapswitch) {
```

To explain, it first loads in the actual files with this part     define(["./properties", "qlik","jquery","highcharts", "bootstrapSwitch"],

That is telling Qlik which JS files to bring in (you dont actually need to put.js after the files.

The error you describe happens when you are not properly passing the stuff inside these js files to the function. This is done in the second part..

```
    function(Props, qlik,$,highcharts,boostrapswitch)
```

You see there are **5 params** because you originally pass **5 js files**.

You need to make sure they are in the same order for both parts.

Here is an example of a Qlik Sense extension, I recommend you examine the properties.js and the TalkToQlik.js to see how it should look.
https://github.com/cookiejest/TalkToQlik

Here is some instructions for that extension:
http://webofwork.com/qlik-sense-voice-control-extension-for-accessibility/

Comment: Hi Cookiejest and thank you for this clear answer. I've struggled a lot with this approuch of creating mash ups and extensions so i did some extra research and looked into about every manual and tutorial there is. At the moment i'm creating my Qlik Sense enviroment with AngularJS and instead of the Capabilities API in the example above i'm using the Qlik Engine API and Web Sockets. I would advice everyone that wants to make a web application with Qlik Sense and for example D3 charts to go this way, You are more free to do what you want.

Comment: I agree that the engine API does allow you get all the functionality. Once you have worked out how to do one standard Json request by an engine call it does become a lot easier to do anything you want and to use the documentation, although this does require a basic understanding of Qlik core product. However since it is fairly complex to get to that stage I recommend people who are web developers more than Qlik experts use the capabilities API. Hopefully these separate APIs will be simplified with future releases.

Comment: AlSo I understand Angular is a very popular framework but is entirely possible and easier to get up and running without angular and embedding Qlik Sense. For anyone else who is reading this.

Comment: Totaly agree with that! But i'm a fulltime web developer and it only took me one month to have a basic understanding of the Qlik Sense API. It's really not that hard, everything is going through Web Sockets. Yes, there is no need to use AngularJS but if you have the time to learn, like i have, challenge yourself and use AngularJS!